# Eclipse 4 RCP - how to remove Part from application model?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have this utility method which allows easily to change what is shown in specific location of my application.

The problem is it looks more like that the new Part is on top of the old Part (the old Part is not removed and it is still visible under the new Part).

```java
package cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc.ui;

import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.MPart;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.MPartSashContainer;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EModelService;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService;

public class UI {

    public static final String PART_INSPECTOR_ID = "bc.part.inspector";

    public static void changeInspectorView(String partDescriptorId, EPartService partService, EModelService modelService) {

        MPart part = partService.createPart(partDescriptorId);
        MPart oldPart = partService.findPart(UI.PART_INSPECTOR_ID);
        MPartSashContainer parent = (MPartSashContainer) modelService.getContainer(oldPart);
        parent.getChildren().remove(oldPart);
        part.setElementId(UI.PART_INSPECTOR_ID);
        parent.getChildren().add(0, part);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```java
partService.hidePart(oldPart);
```

to hide the old part (also removes it from the children).

You might also just be able to do:

```java
oldPart.setToBeRendered(false);
```

but I am not sure that does enough to update the Eclipse internal state.

Comment: If i remember correctly, hidePart makes the part "invisible". This could lead to unexpected beahavior (for example if you have event triggerd methods within this part). hidePart(oldPart,true) forces to remove it as children from the part stack. Only as hint ;)

Comment: @MatthiasH The part is destroyed when it is hidden (just run a test to confirm that)